# Count occurrences of strings separated by a semicolon

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a .csv file which is a database of articles. Each article has some keywords associated, with the number of keywords being different each time.

Something a bit like this :

```
article_id,keywords
1,word1;word2;word3
2,word1;word4
3,word2;word3
```

I would like to count how many times each keyword appear in my .csv file, how could I do this? And yes, they are separated by semicolons.

Here is a sample of the .csv :

```
id,keywords,date,nbComments,nbView,nbStars,nbVotes,source
44941,Alain Soral;Emmanuel Macron;France;François Fillon;Front national;Mélenchon;Politique,2017-04-04 00:00:00,21,101368,5,688,E&R
44309,Féminisme;France;François Hollande;Immigration;Internet;Marine Le Pen;Médias;People;Politique;Terrorisme,2017-02-23 00:00:00,30,43908,5,226,ERTV
45338,Allemagne;France;Histoire;Judaïsme;Médias;Pologne;Seconde Guerre mondiale,2017-04-25 00:00:00,31,24019,4,121,ERTV
```

Comment: did you try anything yet?

Comment: Seems like a simple split, loop, split, and dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the array of keywords...

```
d3.merge(data.map(function(d) {
  return d.keywords.split(";")
}))
```

... and count the occurrences with a `forEach`:

```
var keywords = {};

d3.merge(data.map(function(d) {
  return d.keywords.split(";")
})).forEach(function(d) {
  keywords[d] = (keywords[d] || 0) + 1
})
```

Here is a demo using your CSV (stored in a `<pre>` element, since I cannot use a real CSV in the Stack snippet):

```js
var data = d3.csvParse(d3.select("#csv").text());

var keywords = {};

d3.merge(data.map(function(d) {
  return d.keywords.split(";")
})).forEach(function(d) {
  keywords[d] = (keywords[d] || 0) + 1
})

console.log(keywords)
```

```css
pre {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<pre id="csv">id,keywords,date,nbComments,nbView,nbStars,nbVotes,source
44941,Alain Soral;Emmanuel Macron;France;François Fillon;Front national;Mélenchon;Politique,2017-04-04 00:00:00,21,101368,5,688,E&R
44309,Féminisme;France;François Hollande;Immigration;Internet;Marine Le Pen;Médias;People;Politique;Terrorisme,2017-02-23 00:00:00,30,43908,5,226,ERTV
45338,Allemagne;France;Histoire;Judaïsme;Médias;Pologne;Seconde Guerre mondiale,2017-04-25 00:00:00,31,24019,4,121,ERTV</pre>
```

Comment: +1 Beaten to answering this. Only a minor detail to add; the split should split on , and ; so the split call should use regex and be  d.keywords.split(/[;,]+/);

Comment: @ayls why should it split on comma?

Comment: The sample provided uses both ; and ,. For example this bit here "Terrorisme,2017-02-23 00:00:00,30,43908,5,226,ERTV". But perhaps that is not requirement. Maybe I am just being picky :)

Comment: No, those values go into other objects! Each object goes from one comma to the next. Have a look at the console here: https://jsfiddle.net/uorxathf/

Comment: Yep, aware of what CSV means, no need to be offended ;) It is just that he wants to measure keywords and that can be understood in various ways as far as I am concerned. Have a nice day :)

Comment: @ayls I was not offended! Sorry for the comment, I didn't mean to be sarcastic or anything. I just edited it because I realised it is pretty obvious that you know what CSV means!

Comment: @GerardoFurtado it works perfectly, thanks. Could you explain to me what `keywords[d] = (keywords[d] || 0) + ` does?

edit : specifically the `|| 0`

Comment: @ArnaudStephan That's an OR operator. If the key doesn't exist, it's value will be assigned to zero.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I see. One last thing, with your method I get an object with a lot of properties, one for each of the words present. How could I get an array of objects with two properties instead? One property being the keyword and the other one the number of times it appears?

Comment: Please don't make additional questions in the comments. As this is another issue, post another question.